# How to exclude dependencies brought in during build of UWP project

Tags: uwp

I am using a .Net Framework dependent dll in a UWP application. This dll is indirectly dependent on sni.dll which causes the Windows App Certification Kit  to fail:

```
Supported APIs
Error Found: The supported APIs test detected the following errors:
**API IsTokenRestricted in advapi32.dll is not supported for this application type. sni.dll calls this API**.
Impact if not fixed: Using an API that is not part of the Windows SDK for Microsoft Store apps violates the Microsoft Store certification requirements.
How to fix: Review the error messages to identify the API that is not part of the Windows SDK for Microsoft Store apps. Please note, apps that are built in a debug configuration or without .NET Native enabled (where applicable) can fail this test as these environments may pull in unsupported APIs. Retest your app in a release configuration, and with .NET Native
```

I think this is a sqlclient related dependency that will never be invoked. My application does not "need" sni.dll and when I delete it from the debug build and run the app it works fine. I put this in the Post-Build:

`del "$(TargetDir)sni.dll"`

and the app works as expected.

However, when I publish the package, sni.dll is included in the *x64.msixbundle; specifically in the *.x64.msix bundle inside the *x64.msixbundle; how do I keep the sni.dll file out of my package ?

Comment: I think you should check the  .Net Framework dll and exclude the sni.dll instead of doing it in your UWP project.

Comment: How does the  .Net dll dependent on the sni.dll? Are there any NuGet package references in the .Net dll that rely on the sni.dll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to work around this issue. First, I am confident that sni.dll is unused by my application but is pulled in as a sub-dependency. But where is it coming from? I used Sysinternal's procmon.exe to locate the source MSBuild is using:

```
.nuget\packages\runtime.win-x64.runtime.native.system.data.sqlclient.sni\4.4.0\runtimes\win-x64\native
```

I then picked a dll that I know is UWP compliant and replaced the sni.dll file with the new file. I renamed the new file to sni.dll.

I re-packaged my app and the Windows App Certification Kit does not return the error, and the package made it into the store.